# How to query XML as used in .dtsx (SSIS)

Tags: xml, t-sql, xquery, ssis-2012

I have made an SSIS 2014 package (Project Deployment).

Here you see a (relevant) part of it's XML-content:

```
    <DTS:Executable DTS:refId="Package\Drop and Create statements voor tabellen\Drop and Create Classes_staging" DTS:CreationName="Microsoft.ExecuteSQLTask" DTS:Description="Execute SQL Task" DTS:DTSID="{60C174A8-D9C0-4F2A-B783-77753552BFCB}" DTS:ExecutableType="Microsoft.ExecuteSQLTask" DTS:LocaleID="-1" DTS:ObjectName="Drop and Create Classes_staging" DTS:TaskContact="Execute SQL Task; Microsoft Corporation; SQL Server 2014; © 2014 Microsoft Corporation; All Rights Reserved;http://www.microsoft.com/sql/support/default.asp;1" DTS:ThreadHint="7">
      <DTS:Variables />
      <DTS:ObjectData>
        <SQLTask:SqlTaskData xmlns:SQLTask="www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/dts/tasks/sqltask" SQLTask:Connection="{c25e8858-9d6b-424d-b231-3ae05aed0d4b}" SQLTask:SqlStatementSource="/****** Table [dbo].[Classes_staging] ******/&#xA;IF OBJECT_ID('[dbo].[Classes_staging]') IS NOT NULL&#xA;DROP TABLE [dbo].[Classes_staging];&#xA;GO&#xA;&#xA;CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Classes_staging](&#xA;&#x9;[Reference] [nvarchar](50) NULL) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]&#xA;&#xA;GO&#xA;&#xA;&#xA;" />
      </DTS:ObjectData>
    </DTS:Executable>
```

This file is imported into a table using OPENROWSET:

```
INSERT INTO Packages(XMLContent)
SELECT CONVERT(XML, BulkColumn) AS xContent
FROM OPENROWSET(BULK 'myFile.dtsx', SINGLE_BLOB) AS x;
```

Now I am trying to query it:

```
;WITH XMLNAMESPACES ('www.microsoft.com/SqlServer/Dts' AS  
DTS,'www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/dts/tasks/sqltask' AS SQLTask) 

--Alle Executables
SELECT      Pkg.props.value('./@DTS:DTSID','nvarchar(max)') as [DTSID]
            ,Pkg.props.value('./@DTS:refId','nvarchar(max)') as [Executable]
            ,Pkg.props.value('./@DTS:ObjectName','nvarchar(max)') as [ObjectName]
            ,Pkg.props.value('./@DTS:Description','nvarchar(max)') as [Description]
            ,Pkg.props.value('./@DTS:ExecutableType','nvarchar(max)') as [ExecutableType]
            ,Pkg.props.value('./@SQLTask:SqlStatementSource','nvarchar(max)') as [SqlStatementSource]
FROM    (SELECT XMLContent AS pkgXML FROM packages) t

--CROSS APPLY pkgXML.nodes('//SQLTask:SqlTaskData') Pkg(props)
CROSS APPLY pkgXML.nodes('//DTS:Executable' ) Pkg(props)
```

I can either find all the SQLStatements used in the package **OR** I can find details concerning the executables. I can do this by swapping the two **CROSS APPLY** mentioned above.
But I cannot do both... What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
;WITH XMLNAMESPACES ('www.microsoft.com/SqlServer/Dts' AS  
DTS,'www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/dts/tasks/sqltask' AS SQLTask) 

--Alle Executables
SELECT      X.Exe.value('./@DTS:DTSID','nvarchar(max)') as [DTSID]
            ,X.Exe.value('./@DTS:refId','nvarchar(max)') as [Executable]
            ,X.Exe.value('./@DTS:ObjectName','nvarchar(max)') as [ObjectName]
            ,X.Exe.value('./@DTS:Description','nvarchar(max)') as [Description]
            ,X.Exe.value('./@DTS:ExecutableType','nvarchar(max)') as [ExecutableType]
            ,Y.Task.value('./@SQLTask:SqlStatementSource','nvarchar(max)') as [SqlStatementSource]

FROM    (SELECT XMLContent  AS pkgXML FROM packages) t

CROSS APPLY pkgXML.nodes('//DTS:Executable' ) X(Exe)
OUTER APPLY X.Exe.nodes('./DTS:ObjectData/SQLTask:SqlTaskData') Y(Task)
```

Answer (score 1):

Do another `CROSS APPLY`, which shred the XML on `SqlTaskData`, on the result of the first `CROSS APPLY` :

```
;WITH XMLNAMESPACES ('www.microsoft.com/SqlServer/Dts' AS  
DTS,'www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/dts/tasks/sqltask' AS SQLTask) 

--Alle Executables
SELECT      Y.Task.value('./@DTS:DTSID','nvarchar(max)') as [DTSID]
            ,Y.Task.value('./@DTS:refId','nvarchar(max)') as [Executable]
            ,Y.Task.value('./@DTS:ObjectName','nvarchar(max)') as [ObjectName]
            ,Y.Task.value('./@DTS:Description','nvarchar(max)') as [Description]
            ,Y.Task.value('./@DTS:ExecutableType','nvarchar(max)') as [ExecutableType]
            ,X.Exe.value('./@SQLTask:SqlStatementSource','nvarchar(max)') as [SqlStatementSource]
FROM    (SELECT XMLContent AS pkgXML FROM packages) t

CROSS APPLY pkgXML.nodes('//DTS:Executable' ) X(Exe)
CROSS APPLY X.Exe.nodes('./DTS:ObjectData/SQLTask:SqlTaskData') Y(Task)
```

Comment: Had to switch Y.Task and X.exe in the SELECT statement and make an OUTER APPLY of the second APPLY but that did the trick! Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: Msg 208, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
Invalid object name 'packages'.

Completion time: 2024-03-20T14:17:28.4686461+07:00