# List all data flows in Visual Studio - complete noob

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, ssis

So I am a complete noob when it comes to Visual Studio and only recently started using it as part of a new role.

We have a project in SSIS with 150 packages. Each has a data flow where the data from the table is pushed into our SQL server equivalent table. Both tables have the same name. We discovered that one of the flows was set up with the wrong destination table. This means we now have to check all 150 flows to ensure everything else is correct.

Is there a way that i can list all the data flows and their source and destination details so i can match and compare?

Apologies if using incorrect nomenclature or not providing clear details. Just let me know what you'd need to know.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

[image]

[image]

Comment: What are your skills? Can you handle C#? Are you allowed to install free third party software add-ons for Visual Studio? What source and destination components do the packages use (OLE DB Source, ADO.NET Source, ODBC Source, etc)?

Comment: I can SQL. Never done C# before but hey, how hard can it be? :D
Cannot install third party software.
Using OLE DB for both

Comment: SQL might work in this case, N of 150 packages have a mismatch between the source table and the target. How are the packages deployed (SSISDB?). If they are deployed to the SSISDB, did the execution that loaded the wrong table run there? (The logging might record what the source/destination table names are)

Comment: I added some screenshots of the Flow. I think it's SSISDB, how can I check?
We also built a SQL Server Agent with 150 jobs to refresh the tables on a schedule. An error occurred for one the steps which is how we picked up the problem. When reviewing with my manager, he said this shouldn't have caused a problem but once we changed the destination table to the appropriate one the step was executed successfully. No other steps caused errors.

Comment: You can check if it's the SSISDB by a query like `SELECT TOP 100 * FROM catalog.operations AS O ORDER BY O.operation_id DESC` and if you see packages from the job stream, then you know it's in the SSISDB. Or you can look at your SQL Agent job step and identify from Package Source: SQL Server, File System, or Package Store is the "Package deployment model" and SSIS Catalog is the "Project Deployment model" which is the SSSISDB

Answer (score 0):

If your SSIS project is deployed to SSISDB, you can query tables in it and get source-to-destination mappings for your packages.

I don't have any examples right now, but the following links should give you an idea of which direction to dig to:

- [How to query XML as used in .dtsx (SSIS)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43938001/how-to-query-xml-as-used-in-dtsx-ssis)
- [Finding table name referfences in SSIS packages](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/211796/finding-table-name-referfences-in-ssis-packages)